# multiple site password import

Tags: authentication, sap-commerce-cloud

I am importing data existing systems to hybris system. Our customer has multiple sites and wants to import all users to hybris. But same user exists in multiple sites with different password with different encoding. I have to import all password and encoding, and user can be login to hybris, existing domain with existing password. Normally I can write custom encoding and user can login with one password. How can achieve to import all pasword and encoding to hybris and user can login with pasword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new item model for site based password table and make relation with customer model. 
Then extend new authentication provider from CoreAuthenticationProvider and add it to your *-security-spring-config.xml as authentication-manager.
In new manger override authenticate method.

May be you need to avoid multiple pass for same user. You can redirect to password change page for updating password to OOTB function.